# Transform data into a date in a list and make it functional

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, filter, date

I am having issues trying to transform data into a functioning date in SharePoint Online in a list. The idea is that we display upcoming birthdays for the company but don't display their actual age.

I am having an external data source drop in the data as just mm/dd

[image]

The calculation transforms it into something that looks like a date
[image]

But it doesn't allow it to function as a date
[image]

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH([Birthday]), DAY([Birthday]))

That should get you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
=DATE(2018,LEFT(BirthdayTXT,2),RIGHT(BirthdayTXT,2))
```

[image]

[image]